# SQL Server Backup and Query Execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, backup

Is SQL Server Backup affects the query execution performance? Is there an effect while running the SQL Server backup in remote query execution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes backing up a database will affect performance if you run queries against the server / database.

Your server no matter how amazing it is has a limited amount of resources; backing up the database will add load to the disks and cpu; the amount depending on the size and the options that were chosen for the backup (e.g. compression or verification will add more load.)

What you can do is use a backup strategy that does a full backup at a low utilisation time and smaller incremental [transaction log backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191429.aspx) during the day to minimise the backup time window if you are backing up in operational hours. Or you could investigate alternatives like database [mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189852.aspx) which may help you remove the need to backup the active database; at the cost in terms of extra server resource and a small increase in load on the server for all transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dear. It effect, you just think, you are counting ball in a bucket, at the same time some one throw the some ball. So obviously you are take time to reset again.

The same thing happened in this scenerio. While backup it backup the log and data and the same time you fetch the data.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570804/sql-server-performance-and-query-execution?rq=1

Here is the explanation about database backup.

https://serverfault.com/questions/100490/what-happens-during-a-live-sql-server-backup